# How can I delete package after I make reusable app

Tags: python, django

I make a app named polls copy from (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/reusable-apps/).

When i run `python manage.py startapp polls` the second, raise error "CommandError: 'polls' conflicts with the name of an existing Python module and cannot be used as an app name. Please try another name."

How can i delete the package. I do not want name an anther app.

Comment: You need to change the name

Comment: Is there another plan ? I do not want to change name . It is test for learning

Comment: Delete the `polls` directory.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I had delete the directory and delete the project ，but it is not working . where do you said the polls directory ?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the directory created for the first app, should do the work.

Comment: I had delete folder with `rm -rf mysite`  , but it also not working.

Comment: I had use `pip uninstall polls`, it also not working.